# How to minimise(Memory leak) the app memory in ARKit Scene Click on back button?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, scenekit, arkit

How to minimize the app memory consumption in ARKit Scene after clicking on the back button?

Because every time when I open an ARview in my App, the memory usage is increasing.
When I go back then it does not free the memory and after opening an ARview again, the memory usages increases even further.

```swift
class ARViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
        setupFocusSquare()
    }

    func setupScene() {
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session = session
        sceneView.antialiasingMode = .multisampling4X
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = false
        sceneView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60
        sceneView.contentScaleFactor = 1.3
        enableEnvironmentMapWithIntensity(25.0)
        if let camera = sceneView.pointOfView?.camera {
            camera.wantsHDR = true
            camera.wantsExposureAdaptation = true
            camera.exposureOffset = -1
            camera.minimumExposure = -1
            camera.maximumExposure = 3
        }
    }

    func setupFocusSquare() {
        focusSquare?.isHidden = true
        focusSquare?.removeFromParentNode()
        focusSquare = FocusSquare()
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(focusSquare!)
        textManager.scheduleMessage("TRY MOVING LEFT OR RIGHT", inSeconds: 5.0, messageType: .focusSquare)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The attached source code is not enough to answer how exactly resolve memory leak. I will describe steps how to detect leaks. So, you can add such information to question or maybe resolve an issue by yourself.

Xcode has several instrument to detect memory leaks:

1. Debug Memory Graph. Launch the app in debug mode. Navigate to the screen and back several times so memory growth. Then tap "Debug Memory Graph" button at debug toolbar.

[image: Debug Memory Graph]

So, you will see current memory graph of your app. Try to detect some anomaly at left bar:

[image: memory graph]

Maybe you will see few View Controllers or Scene Views. Try to understand what retain this objects and use weak attribute if needed.

2. Use instruments by click Product -> Profile:

[image: Profile]

2.1. Select Leaks instrument:

[image: Leaks]

Run the app by tap Record button (red circle) and make several navigations to screen with issue and back. At the bottom you will see some leaks if any. Sort them by size and make attention at Responsible Library. There should be your app name.

[image: Responsible Library]

If you find something interesting you can select the row and see responsible stack trace.

2.2 Use Allocations instrument:

[image: Allocations]

Run the app by tap Record button (red circle). Navigate to the screen with issue and tap back once. Then click Mark Generation button:

[image: Mark Generation]

Navigate to the screen with issue and back once more. And click "Mark Generation" once more. Repeat this steps once more and you should see three generations at the bottom:

[image: Generations]

So you will see which objects are stay alive between back and forward. You can expand for example Generation B and see which object is retained. By click to some row your will see responsible code.

Depending on results at previous steps you may understand where problem is and add some code to resolve retain cycle or unnecessary retain of some object.